# how to fix CVE-2019-19646 Sqlite Vulnerability in python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, docker, security

I am facing issue with SQLite vulnerability which fixed in SQLite version 3.31.1.
I am using the python3.7.4-alpine3.10 image, but this image uses a previous version of SQLite that isn't patched.
The patch is available in python3.8.2-r1 with alpine edge branch but this image is not available in docker hub.

Please help how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your choices are limited to two options:

1. Wait for the official patched release
2. Patch it yourself

Option 1 is easy, just wait and the patch will eventually propagate through to docker hub. Option 2 is also easy, just get the code for the image from github, update the versions, and run the build yourself to produce the image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try option 2.